# React - best practices on sharing functions across components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, frontend, refactoring

When following best practices in React, what is the best way to share functions across components? A simple example I have right now is a date formatter that just takes a DateTime and converts it to a string with a static (for now) format of `YYY-MM-DD`

The structure of my code is as follows:

```
1. mainComponent.tsx 
  a. tableOne.tsx
  b. tableTwo.tsx
  c. timeline.tsx
```

Each .tsx file has a corresponding useState. Here's what I have thought of so far. Should I:

1. add the function directly to mainComponent.tsx and pass the function in to the relevant components that need it
2. have a useState specifically for a dateFormatter that the functions that need it can pull as necessary (note that I have run into bugs before where if I update the function and the function is both in the parent & child components, the child component won't rerender with the correct state)
3. Have another file on the mainComponent.tsx level that is specific a dateFormatter.tsx and have the components use it as a global static function.

Maybe there's another option I'm missing? But so far I've been doing a lot of 1 & 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe there's another option I'm missing? But so far I've been doing a lot of 1 & 3.

Following the `1st` option you will end up with *circular dependency* since you will have to import the *child* component and from the *child* component you will have to import the function from *parent*. **However** if it's about passing it as props, it's still problematic since you will have to memoize it in case if you don't want any excessive re-renders.

Personally I'd go with the `3rd` option, but only if you are going to use the mentioned function inside `MainComponent`. If you'd decide to use it also somewhere else, would be best to create a separate directory in the main root, e.g. `utils` with `dateUtils.ts` file to store all of the helper functions related with Date.

Comment: I second this.  Option 3 is the way I treat my react apps.  I might add that I don't put the file directly at the `mainComponent.tsx` level.  I put it into a directory that is at the main level -- Usually called `components`, or `elements` as to not gum up the main directory.

Comment: Excessive re-rendering would only occur if the main component's function updated it would have to update all the child components, but even then, since the function is never changing, would it matter at all? Sorry, my react knowledge isn't the best when it comes to this.

Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @Roy _"since the function is never changing"_ - even if the function never changes, it's still a new function reference between re-renders, which may affect the performance and make the memoization impossible. You would have to wrap it with `useCallback` to prevent this. It's feasible, but time consuming.